# Removing a link from places menu in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu environment. Somehow I accidentally added the shortcut in the "places" bar of Nautilus (Not even sure whether the name of that area is "places" or not.)

[image]

On right-clicking the link to be removed, I can see the remove button but it is not highlighted.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: On clicking the properties , the following options showed up.

[Screenshot showing properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d3Fx.png)

Comment: Could you please show us the `properties` offered in your first screenshot? You also could open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T and enter `ls -l /home/sailesh/Downloads/TEST3*`. What is the outcome?  BTW: What you call 'places' is 'nautilus' and the 'places bar' is the 'Dashboard'.

Comment: @muclux        the terminal gave a messsage: "ls: cannot access '/home/sailesh/Downloads/TEST3QUESTIONS(ASSIGNMENT).docx': No such file or directory"
The properties offered are 'owner access,group access, other access' in permissions menu and 'folder sharing' OPTION

Comment: Weird. Your file seems to be considered as something like a folder as you get permissions for enclosed files. Maybe the `()` are the cause? Could you try to rename the file to something with plain text only? Another idea: Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T, then type `file Downloads/TEST3*` (which determines the file type of your file).

Comment: Renamed the file into "TEST3". No change. Tried terminal command(both before renaming and after renaming). The reply message is "/home/sailesh/Downloads/TEST3.docx: cannot open `/home/sailesh/Downloads/TEST3.docx' (No such file or directory)"